# tar creates an absolute sub directory within the compressed file

Tags: linux, tar, zstd

I would like to `tar` a folder using `zstd`. My folder contains subfolders `a` and `b`.

I am `tar`-ing using this:

`tar --zstd -cvf /dest/path/to/output/archive.tar.zstd /full/path/to/src/folder`

However, this causes `archive.tar.zstd` to contain `/full/path/to/src/folder/` and instead of just `folder`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change (`cd`) to the `/full/path/to/src` directory and tar folder from there.

```
tar --zstd -cvf /dest/path/to/output/archive.tar.zstd folder
```

that's the simplest but there are other ways to accomplish too